# show NA values when subscript out of bound

Tags: r, matrix

Let say I have below matrix

```
Mat = matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(as.character(1:4), as.character(16:19)))
```

Now let say, I want to fetch its column for 2 names i.e.

```
Mat[, c('16', '1')]
```

With this I am getting be low error:

```
Error in Mat[, c("16", "1")] : subscript out of bounds
```

Is there any way to return `NA` values for non-available columns?

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to use some kind of function to try and index, and then put a try/catch inside of it. But I think a bigger question is _why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: something along the lines of `Mat[, which(c('16', '1') %in% colnames(Mat) == TRUE)]`. otherwise a somewhat convoluted tryCatch, but don't know what your use case is. Indeed, why?

Comment: The reason why I need to do this is basically benchmarking my matrix based on a broad external vector (here `x`). I have different matrices with varying rows and columns and I need to look them similar with same columns and rows. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a really weird thing to do, here's a way you could do it:

```
Mat <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(as.character(1:4), as.character(16:19)))

getColumns <- function(Mat, indicies) {
    mat_cols <- colnames(Mat)
    missing <- indicies[!(indicies %in% mat_cols)]
    present <- indicies[(indicies %in% mat_cols)]
    result <- cbind(
        Mat[, present],
        matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(Mat), ncol = length(missing))
    )
    colnames(result) <- c(present, missing)
    return(result)
}

> getColumns(Mat, c("1", "2", "17", "19"))
  17 19  1  2
1  5 13 NA NA
2  6 14 NA NA
3  7 15 NA NA
4  8 16 NA NA
```

Comment: Can be done, and similar could be done for missing rows, though still hoping to hear why this would be useful.